# Finding non-HTML tag words in paragraph

Tags: java, jsoup

I've got something like this:

```
<p id="tire">I need new tires for my car</p>
```

I'm trying to write something that would highlight word(s) that I assign, but NOT the stuff that is considered a tag. For example, if I want to highlight "tire", I'd theoretically see:

```
<p id="tire">I need new <strong>tire</strong>s for my car</p>
```

But unfortunately, I see:

```
<p id="<strong>tire</strong>">I need new <strong>tire</strong>s for my car</p>
```

I'm using just a simple replaceAll(oldWord, newFormat). Is there a library that can help? I am using jsoup to grab the HTML I would be searching through.

Comment: I don't know about the libraries, but you could loop through your string, and set a flag when you hit a "<", and set it back when you hit the corresponding ">" So long as the flag is false, you're not in a tag(assuming valid html, and that no data has "<")

Comment: It's worth a shot - seems really slow though if I have a lot of HTML, no?

Comment: People always attribute "looping" with "slow". The algorithms behind "replaceAll" have to loop the whole string. Java native methods are not magic :)

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the question a little bit.

Comment: How are you getting the word to replace? with a regex?

Comment: I have a list that I iterate through. I then search and replace the HTML for that string with that string wrapped in <strong> tags.

Comment: Is the paragraph the entire HTML string?

Comment: well, it's more like an entire HTML page (body, styles, etc). The issue is that if I have a word like "bod", it would break up the word <body>.

Comment: Have you tried to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the selection method `getElementsContainingOwnText(String searchText)` to select elements that contain the word you are looking for. In this case, "tire".

As an example how it works:

Dummy HTML

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body> 
  <p id="tire">I need new tires for my car</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Our Jsoup code:

```
Elements e = doc.getElementsContainingOwnText("tire");
for (Element el : e) {
    el.text(el.ownText().replace("tire", "<strong>tire</strong>"));
}
```

The resulting document printout:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body> 
  <p id="tire">I need new <strong>tire</strong>s for my car</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find and replace, add a space in front of the word like this " tires"

and in replace `<strong>tire</strong>s`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
replaceAll("tire", "<strong>tire</strong>");
replaceAll("id=\"<strong>tire</strong>\"", "id=\"tire\"");
```

This solves the particular problem, but you can get others I think